# Convert Autodesk Viewer Units to Inches

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using the viewer with the Edit2D library and am trying to convert the length between two x and y points into real measurements.

For example, after a shape is drawn using the polygon tool, I want to get the length of the first edge.
I get the drawn shape and the first two points on the event shown below, get 2 points, and get the distance between them. It seems they are in Autodesk Units or something. Is there an easy way to convert the units to feet or inches?

I have found 
`Edit2DExtension.defaultContext.unitHandler.fromDisplayUnits()` 
as well as 
`Edit2DExtension.defaultContext.unitHandler.toDisplayUnits()` 
and also
`Autodesk.Viewing.Private.convertUnits()`.

I've tried all three, but am unsure how to use them and haven't found any good results with them yet.
There may be a way to do it through Edit2d but I haven't found a way yet and there is next to no documentation I can find on this library.

```
 beforeEdit2DAction(event) {
        
    console.log('After Shape has been drawn -> ', event);
    let shape = event.action.shape;

    let pointA = shape._loops[0][0]; // Value: {x: 21.393766403198242, y: 20.934386880096092}
    let pointB = shape._loops[0][1]; // Value: {x: 25.082155227661133, y: 20.934386880096092}


    // Distance between 2 points (Assuming Autodesk units) 
    let length = Autodesk.Edit2D.Math2D.distance2D(pointA, pointB); // 3.6883888244628906
     
    // Need to convert to real world units (preferably ft or inches)
}
```

The real length is **29.5 FEET**
Any ideas, or comments are welcome! Thanks


Edit: Trying Petr's suggestion here's what it returned:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's an interested question. The "unit handler" keeps track of two types of units:

- layer units (`Edit2DExtension.defaultContext.unitHandler.config.layerUnits`, can be `inch` for example)
- display units (`Edit2DExtension.defaultContext.unitHandler.config.displayUnits`)

These two properties control how the actual lengths and areas are displayed. For example, the unit handler's `toDisplayUnits` method is implemented like so:

```js
    toDisplayUnits(fromUnits, value) {
        this.updateConfig();
        return Autodesk.Viewing.Private.convertUnits(fromUnits, this.config.displayUnits, this.config.scaleFactor, value);
    }
```

With that, configuring `fromUnits` and `displayUnits` (and scale) properly should give you the real measurements you need.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, and it returns a number that is smaller when it should be bigger. The measurement should be 29' 6", and toDisplayUnits() returns 0.302... when I pass in fromUnits = 'in' and value = 3.688388.... I posted a pic into the question above.

Comment: figured it out. made 2 THREE.Vector2 objects. Used unithandler.measuretransform.apply() to each one and then found the distance with those.